# tomcat server times out on start after binding to specific address

Tags: java, tomcat9

I bound my tomcat server to a specific address of a VM it's running on in order to open it up to HTTP requests on port 8443 like thus.

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       address="192.168.122.15"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now the server times out even if I set the start timeout timer to 600 seconds (10 minutes)

I tried the following:
https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/tomcat-takes-forever-to-start-what-can-i-do/
[Tomcat 7 times out during start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194108/tomcat-7-times-out-during-start-up)

Neither of these solutions work.

Comment: Is the `8443` port used by other programs? Is the ip address in your LAN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check connection port and redirection one, as you are trying to redirect to the same port you are binding:

```
<Connector port="8443" [....] redirectPort="8443" />
```

Regards.